# Undo failed encryption?

Tags: data-recovery, disk-encryption

I am on Android 6 (AOKP), TWRP installed, and Xposed/Xprivacy. I wanted to encrypt the device from the settings dialog but apparently that failed - it just sits there with the boot animation doing nothing.

I can adb shell into it, logcat says:

```
06-03 03:58:47.076 E/BootAnimation(22199): couldn't find audio_conf.txt
06-03 03:58:51.208 W/vold    (  260): type=1400 audit(0.0:9568213): avc: denied { read } for name="fd" dev="proc" ino=3926686 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:r:logd:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
06-03 03:58:51.208 W/vold    (  260): type=1400 audit(0.0:9568214): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/248/cwd" dev="proc" ino=3926688 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:r:logd:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0
06-03 03:58:51.208 W/vold    (  260): type=1400 audit(0.0:9568215): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/248/root" dev="proc" ino=3926689 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:r:logd:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0
06-03 03:58:51.208 W/vold    (  260): type=1400 audit(0.0:9568216): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/248/exe" dev="proc" ino=3926690 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:r:logd:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0
06-03 03:59:11.618 W/vold    (  260): type=1400 audit(0.0:9568217): avc: denied { read } for name="fd" dev="proc" ino=3926686 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:r:logd:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
06-03 03:59:11.622 W/vold    (  260): type=1400 audit(0.0:9568218): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/248/cwd" dev="proc" ino=3926688 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:r:logd:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0
06-03 03:59:11.622 W/vold    (  260): type=1400 audit(0.0:9568219): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/248/root" dev="proc" ino=3926689 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:r:logd:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0
06-03 03:59:11.622 W/vold    (  260): type=1400 audit(0.0:9568220): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/248/exe" dev="proc" ino=3926690 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:r:logd:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0
06-03 03:59:11.679 E/Cryptfs (  249): unmounting /data failed: Device or resource busy
06-03 03:59:11.698 W/vold    (  260): type=1400 audit(0.0:9568221): avc: denied { read } for name="fd" dev="proc" ino=3926686 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:r:logd:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
06-03 03:59:11.698 W/vold    (  260): type=1400 audit(0.0:9568222): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/248/cwd" dev="proc" ino=3926688 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:r:logd:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0
06-03 03:59:11.698 W/vold    (  260): type=1400 audit(0.0:9568223): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/248/root" dev="proc" ino=3926689 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:r:logd:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0
06-03 03:59:11.698 W/vold    (  260): type=1400 audit(0.0:9568224): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/248/exe" dev="proc" ino=3926690 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:r:logd:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0
06-03 03:59:11.752 W/vold    (  260): type=1400 audit(0.0:9568225): avc: granted { read write } for name="mmcblk0p32" dev="tmpfs" ino=9999 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:block_device:s0 tclass=blk_file
06-03 03:59:11.752 W/vold    (  260): type=1400 audit(0.0:9568226): avc: granted { read write open } for name="mmcblk0p32" dev="tmpfs" ino=9999 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:block_device:s0 tclass=blk_file
06-03 03:59:11.752 W/vold    (  260): type=1400 audit(0.0:9568227): avc: granted { getattr } for path="/dev/block/mmcblk0p32" dev="tmpfs" ino=9999 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:block_device:s0 tclass=blk_file
06-03 03:59:11.832 W/vold    (  260): type=1400 audit(0.0:9568228): avc: granted { read } for name="mmcblk0p47" dev="tmpfs" ino=10059 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:userdata_block_device:s0 tclass=blk_file
06-03 03:59:11.832 W/vold    (  260): type=1400 audit(0.0:9568229): avc: granted { read open } for name="mmcblk0p47" dev="tmpfs" ino=10059 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:userdata_block_device:s0 tclass=blk_file
06-03 03:59:11.832 W/vold    (  260): type=1400 audit(0.0:9568230): avc: granted { ioctl } for path="/dev/block/mmcblk0p47" dev="tmpfs" ino=10059 ioctlcmd=1260 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:userdata_block_device:s0 tclass=blk_file
06-03 03:59:11.835 E/Cryptfs (  249): Bad magic for real block device /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/extra
06-03 03:59:11.841 D/Cryptfs (  249): Just asked init to shut down class main
06-03 03:59:11.841 W/vold    (  249): emulated unmount requires state mounted
06-03 03:59:11.841 W/vold    (  249): public:179_129 unmount requires state mounted
06-03 03:59:31.935 W/vold    (  260): type=1400 audit(0.0:9568231): avc: denied { read } for name="fd" dev="proc" ino=3926686 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:r:logd:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
06-03 03:59:31.935 W/vold    (  260): type=1400 audit(0.0:9568232): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/248/cwd" dev="proc" ino=3926688 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:r:logd:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0
06-03 03:59:31.935 W/vold    (  260): type=1400 audit(0.0:9568233): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/248/root" dev="proc" ino=3926689 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:r:logd:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0
06-03 03:59:31.935 W/vold    (  260): type=1400 audit(0.0:9568234): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/248/exe" dev="proc" ino=3926690 scontext=u:r:vold:s0 tcontext=u:r:logd:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0
06-03 03:59:32.007 E/Cryptfs (  249): unmounting /data failed: Device or resource busy
06-03 03:59:32.007 W/SocketClient(  249): write error (Broken pipe)
06-03 03:59:32.007 W/SocketClient(  249): Unable to send msg '200 8 -1'
```

Now, is it possible to undo the beginning of the encryption, since apparently no sectors were encrypted yet? Maybe I could somehow overwrite the luks header, restore the original one, or maybe the key (if there is one) is still in memory? I do have a TWRP backup from maybe 2 months ago.

I cannot `su` anymore, so that may be a problem.... it just hangs. But I am afraid that if I reboot, every last chance of recovery will be gone.

mount says:

```
rootfs on / type rootfs (ro,seclabel,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,nosuid,relatime,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=600)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,seclabel,relatime)
selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux type selinuxfs (rw,relatime)
/sys/kernel/debug on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,seclabel,relatime)
none on /acct type cgroup (rw,relatime,cpuacct)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=750,gid=1000)
tmpfs on /mnt type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000)
none on /dev/cpuctl type cgroup (rw,relatime,cpu)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup/bfqio type cgroup (rw,relatime,bfqio)
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system on /system type ext4 (ro,seclabel,noatime,data=ordered)
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdata on /data type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,journal_checksum,journal_async_commit,noauto_da_alloc,errors=panic,data=ordered)
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/cache on /cache type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,journal_checksum,journal_async_commit,noauto_da_alloc,errors=panic,data=ordered)
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/radio on /firmware/radio type vfat (ro,context=u:object_r:firmware_file:s0,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0337,dmask=0227,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=lower,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/adsp on /firmware/adsp type vfat (ro,context=u:object_r:firmware_file:s0,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0337,dmask=0227,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=lower,errors=remount-ro)
tmpfs on /storage type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000)
/dev/block/loop0 on /su type ext4 (rw,seclabel,noatime,data=ordered)
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer here: [Cryptfs : unmounting /data failed: Device or resource busy](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/142320/cryptfs-unmounting-data-failed-device-or-resource-busy)

In short: just rebooting worked, nothing was written to disk at all yet.

Note to self: always make a backup right before potentially destructive operations. Saves quite a lot of headaches :)

The answer above also says booting into safe mode fixes the problem. I have yet to verify that.